# Looking for product of symmetric polynomials evaluated at roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, symmetric-polynomials, roots-of-unity

Consider $a_{1} = \alpha^{N-n}, a_{2} = \alpha^{N-n+1}, a_{3} = \alpha^{N-n+2}, a_{4} = \alpha^{N-n+3}, \cdots, a_{n} = \alpha^{N-1}$ where $\alpha$ is a complex $N$th root of unity where $N = 2 + (n-1)2^{n+1}$.

Let:

$P_{1}(\alpha) = a_{1}a_{2}a_{3} \cdots a_{n}$

$P_{2}(\alpha) = (a_{1} + a_{2})(a_{1} + a_{3})\cdots(a_{n-1} + a_{n})$

$P_{3}(\alpha) = (a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3})(a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{4})\cdots(a_{n-2} + a_{n-1} + a_{n})$

$\vdots$

$P_{n}(\alpha) = (a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} + \cdots + a_{n})$

Is there an elementary expression for $\Pi(\alpha) := P_{1}(\alpha)P_{2}(\alpha) \cdots P_{n}(\alpha)$?

Or given $\Pi(\alpha)$, can one say anything about $\Pi(\alpha^{r})$ where $2 \le r \le N-1$?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think there is an elementary expression? Does it come out nicely for small values of $n$? Is there any particular reason to be interested in this problem only in the case where $N=2+(n-1)2^{n+1}$? Is there any particular reason to be interested in this problem at all? Have you done any work on it? Do you have any partial results? Shouldn't it be tagged number theory, rather than rings-and-algebras?

Comment: $N = 2 + (n-1)2^{n+1}$ comes from degree of product of all degree $n$ polynomials with $0$/$1$ coefficients. 

I think the product of $P_{i}$ can be thought of product of Monomial_symmetric_polynomials. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial#Monomial_symmetric_polynomials

My belief that there may be relation bw diff prod comes from the fact that the symm poly are related to power symm poly. Also angle of prod seem to have simple relation. I felt the magnitude might also have nice relation.

I am only an engineer. There might be connections to alg geom & num theory that I dont see.

Comment: Also product of any two of the Monomial symmetric polynomial seem to have some relation. See 1.4 of this:
http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC3/SymPol.pdf

Comment: One more thing I am almost sure is $\frac{1}{N}\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{N-1}\Pi(\alpha^{r}) = 1$, $\frac{1}{N}\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{N-1}\Pi(\alpha^{r})\alpha^{r(N-t)} = 0$ $\forall t \in [1,n]$ with $n \ge 1$.

Comment: "....product of all degree $\le n$ polynomials with $0/1$..." 

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. It sounds like you have done some computations. Why not let people know what you have found, to save us the effort of repeating what you've already done? 

Comment: No I have pretty much told what I know. 

Comment: one more thing that should be known about the equations in that each term $(a_{i_{1}} + a_{i_{2}}+\cdots+\a_{i_{t}})$ correspond to FFT of size $N$ of some polynomial with coefficients $0/1$ with maximum degree $n$ -$\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{t}x^{i_{j}}$ (the top $N-n$ elements of the vector to be FFTed will be zero). Taking all such products would correspond to FFT of product of all degree $\le$ $n$ polynomials. This is the product $\Pi(\alpha)$. Taking inverse FFT of the products would  give the product of all polynomials with degree $\le n$. This is kind of polynomial version of factorial.

Comment: From this view point $\frac{1}{N}\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{N-1}\Pi(\alpha^{r})\alpha^{-r(N-i)} = $ the $i$th term of the product of all the polynomials.

Hence: $\frac{1}{N}\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{N-1}\Pi(\alpha^{r}) = 1$ and $\frac{1}{N}\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{N-1}\Pi(\alpha^{r})\alpha^{-r(N-t)} = 0$ $\forall t \in [1,n]$ with $n \ge 1$.

Comment: (Some) symmetric polynomials really "like" having roots of unity. I know this statement is rather vague, but I have done some extensive experiments on common roots of certain Schur polynomials, and it is VERY common to have roots of unity as common roots. 
I believe this is due to the Vandermonde formula, so my tip is to try to express your things in Schur basis, and then exploit the Vandermonde expression for Schur polynomials.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson could you explain what you mean by schur basis and so on as an answer?

Comment: Oh, I must have misinterpreted the question a bit, but ok, try to expand the product in $a_1,\cdots,a_n$, and then express in the basis of Schur polynomials in $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$. This might give some insight....

Comment: I issue is I do not know what Schur bassis are and how Schur basis is useful here.